# How to send entity body wrapped in a generic entity type to an Spring API

Tags: java, spring, api, rest

I have few child entities that i want to send to a single API endpoint with seperate API requests, so i wrap them in a parent entity and send it as below.

Main wrapper class

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProfileUpdateRequest<T> {

  private T t;

  public void add(T t) {
    this.t = t;
  }

  public T get() {
    return t;
  }
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class EmailPreferencesUpdateRequest {
  @JsonProperty
  private boolean isAgreedToEmails;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class AddressUpdateRequest {
  private List<UserAddress> addresses;
}
```

Send update email preference request

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/update-email", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=*/*", produces = "application/json")
  @ResponseBody
  public String updateEmailNotificationPreferences(@RequestBody EmailPreferencesUpdateRequest emailPreferencesUpdateRequest,
                                                    HttpServletRequest request) {

    ProfileUpdateRequest<EmailPreferencesUpdateRequest> updateRequest = new ProfileUpdateRequest<>();
    updateRequest.add(emailPreferencesUpdateRequest);
    UriComponents uri = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromHttpUrl(baseUrl + "/user/update")
                .build();
    String urlString = uri.toUriString();
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpEntity<ProfileUpdateRequest> requestWithHeader = new HttpEntity<>(updateRequest, requestHeaders);
    restTemplate.exchange(urlString, HttpMethod.PUT, requestWithHeader, UserEntry.class);
  return "success";
}
```

Send update addresses request

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/update-addresses", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=*/*", produces = "application/json")
   @ResponseBody
   public String updateAddresses(@RequestBody List<UserAddress> userAddresses, HttpServletRequest request) {

      AddressUpdateRequest addressUpdateRequest = new AddressUpdateRequest();
      addressUpdateRequest.setAddresses(userAddresses);
      ProfileUpdateRequest<AddressUpdateRequest> updateRequest = new ProfileUpdateRequest<>();
      updateRequest.add(addressUpdateRequest);
      UriComponents uri = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromHttpUrl(baseUrl + "/user/update")
                .build();
      String urlString = uri.toUriString();
      HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
      RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
      HttpEntity<ProfileUpdateRequest> requestWithHeader = new HttpEntity<>(updateRequest, requestHeaders);
      restTemplate.exchange(urlString, HttpMethod.PUT, requestWithHeader, UserEntry.class);
  return "success";
}
```

API endpoint

```
@Path("/user/update")
@PUT
public UserEntry updateUser(ProfileUpdateRequest profileUpdateRequest) {
   if (profileUpdateRequest.get() instanceof AddressUpdateRequest) {
        // update addresses
    } else if (profileUpdateRequest.get() instanceof EmailPreferencesUpdateRequest) {
        // update emails
    }
}
```

From the endpoint i need to get the entity as in `ProfileUpdateRequest` type and check the instance what type of entity i have wrapped so i can pass to the relevant operation. But im getting it as a LinkedHashMap. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways -

1. Either convert profileUpdateRequest.get() , to one of the Object if works thats fine , if not you will get the exception, then convert to other one.
2. Your linkedHashMap will contain the field in the object i.e. for EmailPreferencesUpdateRequest it will contain a key like "isAgreedToEmails", check in the Map with if else, and , then using ObjectMapper do below -

   EmailPreferencesUpdateRequest emailRequest = new ObjectMapper().readValue(YourMap, EmailPreferencesUpdateRequest.class);

Comment: i updated the question, actually i need check  the type of the wrapped entity so i can pass it tot the relevant operation

Comment: There are 2 ways - Either convert profileUpdateRequest.get() , to one of the Object if works thats fine , if not you will get the exception, then convert to other one, or Your linkedHashMap will contain the field in the object i.e. for  EmailPreferencesUpdateRequest it will contain a key like "isAgreedToEmails", check in the Map with if else, and , then using ObjectMapper do below - EmailPreferencesUpdateRequest  emailRequest =
    new ObjectMapper().readValue(YourMap, EmailPreferencesUpdateRequest.class);